# Change key of and group javascript objects with lodash

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have an object structured as follows:

```
{  
   guid x: { id: guid x, fooid: guid a, c: "baz"}, 
   guid y: { id: guid y, fooid: guid a, c: "baz"}, 
   guid z: { id: guid z, fooid: guid b, c: "baz"} 
}
```

I would like to use fooid as key. However some objects have the same fooid and should be grouped (here as an array but could also be object):

```
{  
   guid a : [{ id: guid x, fooid: guid a, c: "bar"},{ id: guid y, 
                fooid: guid a, c: "bar"}],
   guid b : { id: guid z, fooid: 3, c: "bar"} 
}
```

I've tried doing this with lodash but with no success, any help appreciated! Tried to search for solutions, but I'm not sure what about the terminology which makes it very hard.

Comment: what is `id (1)`?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't starting with an array? Syntax shown is invalid for object keys but would make sense for a *"groupBy"* result object

Comment: I wanted to show that the key is the same as the id in the inner object. Not sure how to put it so it becomes clear?
    { 
        guid x : { id: guid x, fooid: guid y, c: "bar"},
        guid z : { id: guid z, fooid: guid y, c: "bar"},
        guid k : { id: guid k, fooid: guid j, c: "bar"}
    }
It's an object, my attempt to simplify might have messed up the syntax.

Comment: Still not clear what you are actually starting with though. Are you sure it is an object or is it an array?

Comment: It's an object with nested objects, I'm sure. Thats on purpose and created with normalizer (https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr).
I updated the question, I think thats correct syntax in the origin at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lodash's [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy):

```js
var data = {  
   "guid x": { id: "guid x", fooid: "guid a", c: "baz"}, 
   "guid y": { id: "guid y", fooid: "guid a", c: "baz"}, 
   "guid z": { id: "guid z", fooid: "guid b", c: "baz"} 
};

var result = _.groupBy(data, 'fooid');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lodash I think this is what you are looking for

```js
var data ={  
   1 : { id: 1, fooid: 200, c: "baz"} ,
   2 : { id: 2, fooid: 200, c: "baz"} ,
   3 : { id: 3, fooid: 300, c: "baz"} ,
}

var res = _(data)
            .values()
            .groupBy('fooid')
            .value()

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, notice i've have used ES6 syntax

```js
var obj = {  
   id1: { id: 1, fooid: 2, c: "baz"},
   id2: { id: 2, fooid: 2, c: "baz"},
   id3: { id: 3, fooid: 3, c: "baz"} 
};

const newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((oldVal, newKey) => {
  
  const key = 'fooid' + obj[newKey]['fooid'];
  
  if(!oldVal.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    oldVal[key] = [];
  }
 
 
  oldVal[key].push(obj[newKey])
  
  return oldVal;
  
},{});

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: you can use reduce method of lodash.